# Display Wordpress Site Title

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display the Title of my Wordpress Site on the single blog posts pages.

I use the following line of code in my theme's 'single blog post.php'

```
<h1><?php $site_title = get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
```

However it does not show anything.

Comment: where is your line of code? : )

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

Comment: Are you actually echoing $site_title anywhere?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You are not outputting anything to show. You are only assigning blog name to a variable. You need to echo the content. It should be :

```
<h1><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You can further reduce this to `<h1><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>`

Comment: Or even `<?php echo get_option( 'blogname' ); ?>` which is what `<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>` runs anyway

Comment: @Selrond Where do you have `blogname` from. WordPress code reference tells differently: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/

Comment: You should always escape HTML in output to mitigate XSS attacks by `<?php echo esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

To display the WordPress site title in your theme, you can use the `wp_title` function or the `bloginfo` function. Here's an example of how to do this:

**1. Using `wp_title` function:**

In the `header.php` file of your WordPress theme, you can add the following code inside the `<title>` tag:

```php
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
```

This will display the site title followed by a separator (specified as '|') and the page/post title.

**2. Using `bloginfo` function:**

You can also use the `bloginfo` function to display the site title within the `<title>` tag. Place this code within the `<head>` section of your theme's `header.php` file:

```php
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
```

This code will output the website title specified in the WordPress settings.

Remember, it's essential to modify theme files carefully, and it's a good practice to create a child theme to make changes to the theme's functionality without affecting the original theme files directly. Always back up your files before making any modifications.

Comment: I rolled back your edit that added a seemingly unnecessary link to your answer. In fact, that link looked a bit like spam, so it's best to avoid adding those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code in this approach.
Create a new variable that has the value of the Site name.
You can use this code.

```
<?php
    $site_title = get_bloginfo('name');
    echo "<h1>" . $site_title . "</h1>";
?>
```

Style the H1 as per your needs.